# How to make each item in listview as column flutter

Tags: flutter

I work in listview in flutter and because I am a new developer in flutter, I face some difficulties in designing the listview.Now the list works with me, As follows:

[image: 1]

Now it's as Row all data see as Row or in one line. I try to make it like column each item in it as Separate column.So will be come first Column image as center , second Column text , third Column text like that.From top to bottom.

This is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String getID;
    getID=  widget.itemHolder.toString();
    return FutureBuilder<List<Flowerdata>>(
                future: fetchFlowers(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {

                if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                );
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.map((data) => Column(children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: ()=>{getItemAndNavigate(data.id ,context)
                      },
                      child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                    child:
                                    Image.network(data.ImageURL,
                                      width: 200, height: 100, fit: BoxFit.cover,))),

                            Flexible(child:
                            Text(data.Name,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)
                            )
                            ),
                            Flexible(child:
                            Text(data.SendFrom,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)
                            )
                            ),

                             FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: () {

                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddComments( UserPostID: UserPostID,psoid:psoid.toString()),));
                              },

                              child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            ),
                          ]

                      ),
                    ),

                    Divider(color: Colors.black),

                  ],))
                      .toList(),

                );
              },
            );

  }
}
```

If anyone knows the solution to a problem please help me.

Comment: Just remove the Row inside GestureDetector. Then remove GestureDetector. Wrap it on top of Column. Now you layout looks like this: GestureDetector->Column->children

Comment: Hi bro . If I do that I get Black screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 return ListView(
          children: [
            for (var data in snapshot.data)
              GestureDetector(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(),
                    Text(data),
                    Text(data),
                    Text(data),
                  ],
                ),
              )
          ],
        );
```

OR

```
 return ListView(
          children: [
            snapshot.data.map((data) => GestureDetector(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(),
                      Text(data),
                      Text(data),
                      Text(data),
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
          ],
        );
```

Comment: Good answer. Its better to use the map.Why is there an unnecessary row though?

Answer (score -2):

just add Scaffold on page top level

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: ListView
    )
```

Comment: thats not what he is asking for.

Comment: Hi bro. I need all list as Column